# How to get last box in vertical mode?

Tags: tex-core, boxes, plain-tex

I'm trying to get the contents of a paragraph with `\showbox` via `\vadjust`, by overloading `\par`.

I came up with this:

```
\showboxdepth\maxdimen
\showboxbreadth\maxdimen
\let\oldvadjust\vadjust
\def\vadjust{
  \begingroup
  \def\par{\endgraf\endgroup\setbox0\lastbox\showbox0}
  \oldvadjust
}
Hello \vadjust{}world.
\bye
```

I get this error:

```
You can't use `\lastbox' in vertical mode.
```

Is there a way to get the contents of a paragraph with `\showbox` (except explicitly doing `\setboxN=\vbox{...}`)?

Comment: You can't use `\lastbox` in the main vertical list. See p. 42 of `TeX By Topic` for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use luatex (and access the box node from lua) or to typeset your paragraph in a vbox, not on the main vertical list so that you are in inner vertical mode, where `\lastbox` is allowed.

Comment: Do you know how to do this in luatex? A little example in the answer is appreciated.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko not exactly, although in general you have access to TeX's box tree as a linked tree of lua nodes that you can inspect, and with care modify. Code example would take too much time during the day, I would probably be forced to read the manual or some such disaster:-)