# How can I get all box of a vertical list?

Tags: tex-core, boxes

I know \lastbox is the last box in current list. Now my questuin is how can I access all boxes in current list.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general you can not access all the items (unless using luatex).

If the list contains removable items you can use `\lastbox`, `\unskip`, `\unpenalty` etc and remove items one at a time from the end of the list, however if the list has any non-removable items, a rule, or `\write` or `\special` whatsit for example, then the items in the list before that are not accessible. You can try to vsplit the list to get a list above the non-removable items but it is not possible to find the full list structure.

Comment: Hi, I have seen your previous answer :-) here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264669/how-to-get-last-box-in-vertical-mode

Comment: @Sebastiano that's a rather different question, what to do on the main vertical list when `\lastbox` is not available.

Comment: I have understood. Thanks for your clarification.